# Prolog: working with lists

Tags: list, prolog

I got this assignment with Prolog lists and I need some help.

Build a program in Prolog that

1. Check if a list is empty
2. Check if a list is not empty
3. Check if a list only has one element
4. Check if a list has 2 or more elements
5. Get the first element from a list
6. Get the second element from a list
7. Get a list without the first element (tail)
8. Add an element to the head of the list

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please take the tour, and read [how to ask questions on this site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are the very beginning of prolog.  These questions mostly relate to how prolog unifies variables and expressions.

1. Check if a list is empty

   ```
   empty([]).
   ```

   In prolog, you state facts and predicates.  Here, you are simply stating that any empty list is true.  It is implied that all other expressions are false.
2. Check if a list is not empty

   ```
   not_empty([_|_]).
   ```

   (Improved by lurker).  This rule matches a list that has at least a head and zero or more tail elements, so empty list would fail.
3. Check if a list only has one element

   ```
   one([_]).
   ```

   When prolog checks this fact, it can only bind to a list with one element.  So the fact it bound already proves it is a one element list.
4. Check if a list has 2 or more elements

   ```
   two([_,_|_]).
   ```

   The first 2 underscores bind to 2 elements in the list, the 3rd underscore to zero or more trailing elements.  So this will only evaluate to true on lists with two or more elements.
5. Get the first element from a list

   ```
   first([H|_], H).
   ```

   Prolog will bind `H` to the first element of the list in the first argument and the second argument.  You call it with `first([1,2,3],F).`.  Prolog will bind `F` to the first element of the list.  You can also call it with `first([1,2,3],1).` to ask if `1` is the first element.
6. Get the second element from a list

   ```
   second([_,I|_], I).
   ```

   Just using simple binding, the first underscore binds with the first element, `I` with the second element, and the second underscore with the rest of the list, (if any).  If you start asking for much higher elements, it is easier to use built-in predicates like `nth1` to do the work for you.
7. Get a list without the first element (tail)

   ```
   tail([_|T],T).
   ```

   Prolog binds the tail to `T`, which must match the second `T` to be considered true.
8. Add an element to the head of the list

   ```
   addelem(H,T,[H|T]).
   ```

   Just using Prolog binding, the `H` will be bound to the front of the list in the 3rd argument, and `T` to the tail of the list.  Call with

   - `addelem(1,[2,3,4],T).` — Binds `T` to `[1,2,3,4]`.
   - `addelem(1,[2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]).` — Proves that this result is correct.
   - `addelem(H, [2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]).` — Pulls the first element of the 3rd argument, if the second argument matches the tail.
   - `addelem(1, T, [1,2,3,4]).` — another way of getting the tail, if the head is `1`.

Comment: Perhaps a better definition of not-empty: `not_empty([_|_]).` *i.e.*, it has one or more elements.

Comment: @lurker. Not "perhaps", but **definitely!** Consider the query `?- not_empty(List).` Which answer(s) *should* we get and which ones DO we actually get with above definition?

Comment: I strongly support what lurker and repeat are saying: The wording of this answer is extremely one-sided and not general enough to describe what these predicates actually mean. For example, these predicates can not only check, but also *generate* solutions. Better use much more general wording: "This relation **is true** if ...".